# Is there any way to avoid this "Attribute value must be constant" error?

Tags: java, annotations

We have an annotation that we have built which is used to validate input to a method. Something like this:

```
@InputValidation(paramName = "foo", regularExpression = RegularExpressionConstants.FOO_REG_EX)
```

Our `RegularExpressionConstants` class has a load of different string constants, all representing different regular expressions. This class was starting to look very messy, so I started trying to tidy it up with methods that make it a bit easier to read etc. So the class now looks like this:

```
public static final String FOO_REG_EX = alphanumericWithRange(1, 16);
public static final String BAR_REG_EX = alphanumericWithRange(2,4);

private static String alphanumericWithRange(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
    "[a-zA-Z0-9]{" + lowerLimit + "," + upperLimit + "}";
}
```

The RegularExpressionConstants class compiles, but the annotations are no longer compiling. The error is `Attribute value must be constant`. After looking at some of the related questions on StackOverflow, I understand why this is happening. I am mainly wondering if there is any way I can achieve the tidiness I want in the constants class without causing this issue? Or am I just going to have to deal with lots of messy constants?

Comment: You have already named constants (considering that you actually use better names than `FOO_REG_EX` and `BAR_REG_EX`), so there is no need for additional “tidiness” by using, e.g. `alphanumericWithRange(1, 16)` instead of `"[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,16}"` or `"\\p{Alnum}{1,16}"`. Using an additional method here is overengineered.

Comment: @Holger it isn't just about tidiness though. It's also that when another developer adds a regex, and they know their regex needs to be an alphanumeric, they can call the existing method without having to worry about writing a whole new regular expression. Reduces the risk of errors, and saves future developers time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an enum instead of a list of string constants:

```
@interface InputValidation {
    RegularExpressionConstants regularExpression() default 
             RegularExpressionConstants.FOO_REG_EX;
}
```

Using an enum allows also moving the `name` metadata where the pattern is defined

```
enum RegularExpressionConstants {
    FOO_REG_EX("foo", alphanumericWithRange(1, 16)), 
    BAR_REG_EX("bar", alphanumericWithRange(2,4));

    private final String name;
    private final String pattern;

    private RegularExpression(String name, String pattern) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    private static String alphanumericWithRange(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) {
        return "[a-zA-Z0-9]{" + lowerLimit + "," + upperLimit + "}";
    }
}
```

And the annotation can be applied using the enum:

```
@InputValidation(regularExpression=RegularExpressionConstants.FOO_REG_EX)
```

Where the annotation is processed, it's enough to just call:

```
String pattern = field.getAnnotation(InputValidation.class)
    .regularExpression()
    .getPattern();
```

Comment: I don't get it, how is this helpful now? OP expects a `regex` (String) for the annotation and now he gets an `enum`; I don't think it's an option refactoring this entirely

Comment: @Eugene I was just adding that. In addition to solving the problem, the enum is a better alternative to string constants

Comment: This is a good idea. If I change my code that uses the annotation to expect an enum instead of a string, then this is a definite option. I'll give it a go and then once i've validated that it works, i'll come back and accept your answer :)

Comment: @ernest_k apparently the OP is willing to change his code, I was wrong, which is good. 1+

Answer (score 1):

Unless you follow [ernest's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254066/1059372) and refactor the code, you simply can't. The missing part in your case is an enforcement by the `JSL` (for what a compile time constant is)

> initialized with a constant expression

and calling a method is simply not; even if you can tell that this is a constant, the compiler can't and will not.